# OpenFiler and Raid 1

Tags: software-raid, openfiler

I am looking to deploy a new OpenFiler NAS box. I have setup 2 1TB drives for Raid 1 (software raid built into OpenFiler)and the boot is on a 320GB HDD.
When trying to simulate a crash (remove one of the 1tb drives)the system hangs...and reboots....it continues a reboot cycle until the drive is put back in??

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you're just doing this on a regular desktop, it's probably because the drives are not hot-swappable. Removing or adding hard drives to a system when one or the other does not support hot-swap is a sure way to destroy the system and/or the drive.